# Azure - Unable to choose correct subscription from list

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I am an administrator on a number of client azure accounts.

I am trying to publish a service from Visual Studio 2013 and cannot work out how to decide the correct "subscription" to publish to using the VS publishing wizard...

There are numerous options named identically making it impossible to decide...

This is what I see

[image]

Can anyone help me work out how to identify which is which?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would change the names. You can do this by going to  [subscriptions](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions). Click on the desired Subcription to rename than choose 'Edit Subscription Details'